# How to get x y coordinates for mouse positioning in mobile mode (for mobile resolution) on desktop

Tags: javascript, angular

I found below code working to track the mouse positioning on a web page in desktop mode but the same is not working when I change the resolution to the mobile device. **I need code that should work from the console** as the below code. any help please.

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) { document.title = "X: " + e.pageX + " - Y: " + e.pageY; };
```

Comment: But a mobile phone wouldn't have a mouse (pointer)?

Comment: try `e.clientY` and `e.clientX`

Comment: I have found both statements working only when I click on the mouse position. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`onmousemove` requires that there be a mouse, which a mobile device would not have (as @George points out in a comment).

A possible fix would be to use `window.pageXOffset` / `window.pageYOffset`, which will get the scroll location; you could update that by registering a callback for `onscroll` (instead of `onmousemove`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events has some good advice on how to code around touch events (many of which are implemented as overriding mouse functionality); you may also be able to put something together using that.  If you go that route, you'll have to think of the mouse as a finger, and presume a touch to be equivalent to a click - a touch interface has no way of detecting what part of the screen a finger is hovering over prior to it touching the screen.